# FindBy in pageFactory (webdriver) doesn't work correctly

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to write tests in selenium `WebDriver` with `PageFactory`, but if I add annotations in `PageFactory` form in class

```
@FindBy(id="email")
public WebElement mailLink;
```

and usage:

```
mailLink.sendKeys("mail@mail.com");
```

I get a `NullPointerException` every time. Another way:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("mail@mail.com");
```

returns correct value. Where is the problem with first method?

My code:

I have got driver initialization in FaceClass:

```
public class FaceClass {

protected WebDriver driver;

public FaceClass(WebDriver driver){
    this.driver = driver;
}

public HomePage navigateToApp(){
    driver.navigate().to("https://facebook.pl");

    return PageFactory.initElements(driver, HomePage.class);
}
```

}

and class with business logic:

```
public class HomePage extends FaceClass{

public HomePage(WebDriver driver) {
    super(driver);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


@FindBy(id="email")
public WebElement mailLink;

@FindBy(id="pass")
public WebElement passLink;

@FindBy(how = How.ID, using="u_0_n")
public WebElement loginButton;


public ProfilePage navigateToProfile(){

    try{

        if(driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).isEnabled() || driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).isDisplayed()){
            System.out.println("ok!");
        }



    //driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys("pass_to_account");
    //driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("mail@mail.com");
    //driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_n")).click();
    mailLink.sendKeys("mail@mail.com");
    passLink.sendKeys("pass_to_account");
    loginButton.click();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return PageFactory.initElements(driver, ProfilePage.class);
}
```

}

and test:

```
    public class ExampleTest {

WebDriver driver;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.navigate().to("https://facebook.pl");
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {

    driver.quit();
}

@Test
public void test() {
    //fail("Not yet implemented");
    HomePage homepage = new HomePage(driver);
    homepage.navigateToProfile();

}
```

}

All elements are enabled and visible

Comment: Did you initialize your driver properly in the earlier case? You may provide your code portion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not initialize your elements before using. To initialize your page elements PageFactory method initElements. It's better if you call it in your constructor like this:

```
public HomePage(WebDriver driver) {
    super(driver);
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}
```

Hope it works.